# Water Pump Thrust Calculation

Tags: open-channel-flow

If I have a water pump positioned horizontally where the diameter of the inlet and the outlet of the water is equal: Din = Dout. If the volume flow rate is know experimentally by measuring the time taken to fill a container with a known volume. Is it possible to calculate thrust force of the water pump based on these information? If possible how? If not why?

Answer (score 2):

This is enough information to determine thrust provided you know the actual value of output diameter Dout because it is the only given distance measure.
Cross sectional area m^2 = Pi * (Dout m / 2)^2

So lets reduce everything to what happens during 1 second of continuous flow.

initial velocity at input m/s = 0 m/s
final velocity at output m/s = volumetric flow rate m^3/sec / cross sectional area m^2
mass kg = volumetric flow rate m^3/sec * density kg/m^3 * 1 sec
acceleration m/s^2 = (final velocity m/sec - initial velocity m/sec) / (1 sec - 0 sec)
thrust N = mass kg * acceleration m/s^2

Thrust in Newtons N, is the force required to accelerate 1 kg of mass to 1 meter per second per second.

We know that the pump is producing a constant acceleration if the flow rate is uniform.